# Getting a list of values from a list of dict in python: Without using list comprehension

Tags: python

I have a list of dict for example,

```
[{'id': 1L, 'name': u'Library'}, {'id': 2L, 'name': u'Arts'}, {'id': 3L, 'name':  u'Sports'}]
```

Now, I have to retrieve the following list from this dict without using list comprehension

```
[u'Library', u'Arts', u'Sports']
```

Is there any way to achieve this in python? I saw many similar questions, but all answers were using list comprehension.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you so scared of list comprehensions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

categories = map(itemgetter('name'), things)
```

But a list comprehension is good too. What's wrong with list comprehensions?

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) here. `map()` applies the lambda to every item of `testList` and returns it as a list.

```
>>> testList = [{'id': 1L, 'name': u'Library'}, {'id': 2L, 'name': u'Arts'}, {'id': 3L, 'name':  u'Sports'}]
>>> map(lambda x: x['name'], testList)
[u'Library', u'Arts', u'Sports']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) with [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms):

```
>>> dlist = [{'id': 1L, 'name': u'Library'}, {'id': 2L, 'name': u'Arts'}, {'id': 3L, 'name':  u'Sports'}]

>>> map(lambda d: d['name'], dlist)
[u'Library', u'Arts', u'Sports']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here -

```
ltemp = [] 
for i in dictT:
    ltemp.append(i['name'])
```

ltemp is required list. And dictT is your list of dictionaries.